# [Unity3D]How to get reference to a specific Animation Clip in Animator

Tags: unity-game-engine

For the past 2 hours I have been searching everywhere and I can't find any resources to help me. The documentation is confusing (Especially for Animation) and every information I find is for a previous version of Unity that had a different animation system. Anyway, I have a GameObject with a Animator component attached. The Animator Controller has 4 animation states that it uses. I have a script attached to my GameObject and I can'd find out how to do the following:
1) Get the length any specific clip
2) Change the speed of any specific clip.

animator.speed = (some number) does not work because it changed the speed of ALL the clips. I want to change the speed of specific clips during runtime. Is there a way I can search the animation clip by name and change the clip speed? Or is there a way I can make a public AnimationClip, drag and drop the clip, and then edit the speed of the clip? And I want to change all of this during runtime, I know I can click on the Animation Clip and change the speed that way. Also, as I listed earlier, I need to get the length of the animation clip. I assume if I can change the speed of an animation clip, I can get the length of the clip because I'd have the reference to it. Any Help?

Comment: Have you tried setting the AnimationState.speed?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips(GameObject)
```

By using this you will get all animationsClips in array from current gameObject. Then you will have everything you want.

See docs:

[AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips.html)
[AnimationClip](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.html)

Comment: Getting the animation clips is not helpful since you cannot modify their speed. You need the Animator for global control or the AnimationState for local control. Clips are immutable. The only thing that would be close to speed is the frame rate but is readonly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I posted this as answer because of my reputation - I can not post comment under question. 

At least he will have access to "length". This, and your answer (AnimationState.speed) should do the job.